# How to make drag to scroll work smoothly with scroll snapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

Scroll snapping works well with mouse scroll but not with drag to scroll.

I want to be able to actually scroll and then for it to snap in place like it does with normal scrolling.
So I want for it to move normally while I drag scroll(no snapping) and once I leave it, I would like it to travel and snap.
Just don't want a slideshow while drag scrolling.

Any alternative solution?

```js
const childern = document.querySelectorAll(".childern");
const parent = document.querySelector(".container");

let startX;
let scrollTop;
let isDown;

parent.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => mouseIsDown(e));
parent.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => mouseUp(e));
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => mouseLeave(e));
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => mouseMove(e));

function mouseIsDown(e) {
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - parent.offsetTop;
  scrollTop = parent.scrollTop;
}
function mouseUp(e) {
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseLeave(e) {
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseMove(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Move vertcally
    const y = e.pageY - parent.offsetTop;
    const walkY = (y - startY) * 5;
    parent.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.childern {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.one {
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}
.three {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="childern one"></div>
      <div class="childern two"></div>
      <div class="childern three"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually found a solution for it.

So in javascript, when mouse is held down (`function mouseIsDOwn`), set `scroll-snap-type = "none"` and when mouse is released (`function mouseUp`) set `scroll-snap-type = "y mandatory"`
I hope it helps if someone else is looking for this.

Comment: Works well enough in Chrome, but does not work very will in Safari.

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome for me too, but Chrome animation looks a bit sharpening when an item snapped to the point. By the way, Firefox moves it smoothly. And Safari stays in the start position with any drag scrolling. Trying to find out. )

Answer (score 4):

Add scroll-behavior: smooth; in .container class

```js
const childern = document.querySelectorAll(".childern");
const parent = document.querySelector(".container");

let startX;
let scrollTop;
let isDown;

parent.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => mouseIsDown(e));
parent.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => mouseUp(e));
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => mouseLeave(e));
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => mouseMove(e));

function mouseIsDown(e) {
  isDown = true;
  startY = e.pageY - parent.offsetTop;
  scrollTop = parent.scrollTop;
}
function mouseUp(e) {
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseLeave(e) {
  isDown = false;
}
function mouseMove(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Move vertcally
    const y = e.pageY - parent.offsetTop;
    const walkY = (y - startY) * 5;
    parent.scrollTop = scrollTop - walkY;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.childern {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.one {
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}
.three {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">
      <div class="childern one"></div>
      <div class="childern two"></div>
      <div class="childern three"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is simple fix, implemented similar code for dragging, using tailwind utility classes and wanted to add scroll snap - found the same issues as OP, adding the class .scroll-smooth works a treat

Comment: is there anyway to get the current children being displayed?