How to implement snapping animation in to a momentum based drag scrolling?
I have a momentum based drag scrolling and I implement snapping behavior. The problem is the snapping animation is instantaneous. How to make it smoother?
I try this using the momentum based horizontal drag by Lachlan https://codepen.io/loxks/details/KKpVvVW


const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  slider.classList.remove('snap');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  cancelMomentumTracking();
});


slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
  slider.classList.add('snap');
});


slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
  slider.classList.add('snap');
  beginMomentumTracking();
});


slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  var prevScrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  velX = slider.scrollLeft - prevScrollLeft;
});

// Momentum 

var velX = 0;
var momentumID;

slider.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  cancelMomentumTracking();
});

function beginMomentumTracking() {
  cancelMomentumTracking();
  momentumID = requestAnimationFrame(momentumLoop);
}

function cancelMomentumTracking() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(momentumID);
}

function momentumLoop() {
  slider.scrollLeft += velX;
  velX *= 0.95;
  if (Math.abs(velX) > 0.5) {
    momentumID = requestAnimationFrame(momentumLoop);
  }
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik);
body,
html {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh
}

.grid-item {
  color: #fff;
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 3.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100vh
}

.main {
  color: #959595;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #5bbce4;
  grid-area: footer;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  will-change: transform;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items.active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: skyblue;
  min-height: 250px;
  min-width: calc(100vw - 2rem);
  margin: 2em 1em;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.snap {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
<div class="grid-container">


  <main class="grid-item main">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item item1"></div>
      <div class="item item2"></div>
      <div class="item item3"></div>
      <div class="item item4"></div>
    </div>

  </main>

</div>



I also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962715/how-to-make-drag-to-scroll-work-smoothly-with-scroll-snapping but the animation is instant. I also tried the no.2 solution by adding style= "scroll-behavior: smooth;" in the parent .items but the scroll is too sticky, it does not even let me scroll.
I expect to make the snapping animation smoother, also if you can make the item scale up when it is in the center of the screen and scale down when they are not. I appreciate it. Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
